# How to translate TF Dense layer to PyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, torch

I am wondering if someone can help me understand how to translate a short TF model into Torch.

Consider this TF setup:

```
inp = layers.Input(shape = (386, 1024, 1), dtype = tf.float32)
x = layers.Dense(2)(inp)  # [None, 386, 1024, 2]
start, end = tf.split(x, 2, axis=-1)
start = tf.squeeze(start, axis = -1)
end = tf.squeeze(end, axis = -1)
model = Model(inputs = inp, outputs = [start, end])
```

Specifically, I am not sure what Torch command would turn my data from `386, 1024, 1` to `386, 1024, 2` nor do I understand anything that this says its doing: `Model(inputs = inp, outputs = [start, end])`

Is:

```
inp = layers.Input(shape = (386, 1024, 1), dtype = tf.float32)
x = layers.Dense(2)(inp)  # [None, 386, 1024, 2]
```

Equivalent to:

```
X = torch.randn(386, 1024, 1)
X = X.expand(386, 1024, 2)
X.shape [386, 1024, 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TF -> Torch** when build the model is basically straight forward, you can usually find Torch function that equivalent to TF function in [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html), following is the example of convert the TF code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import numpy as np

inp = layers.Input(shape = (386, 1024, 1), dtype = tf.float32)
x = layers.Dense(2)(inp)  # [None, 386, 1024, 2]
start, end = tf.split(x, 2, axis=-1)
start = tf.squeeze(start, axis=-1)
end = tf.squeeze(end, axis=-1)
model = models.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = [start, end])

X = np.random.randn(3, 386, 1024, 1)
output = model(X)
print(output[0].shape, output[1].shape)

# Outputs: (3, 386, 1024) (3, 386, 1024)
```

To Torch code:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
      super(Net, self).__init__()
      self.fc = nn.Linear(1, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
      x = self.fc(x)
      start, end = torch.split(x, 1, dim=-1)
      start = torch.squeeze(start, dim=-1)
      end = torch.squeeze(end, dim=-1)
      return [start, end]

net = Net()

X = torch.randn(3, 386, 1024, 1)
output = net(X)
print(output[0].size(), output[1].size())

# Outputs: torch.Size([3, 386, 1024]) torch.Size([3, 386, 1024])
```

And the following TF code:

```
inp = layers.Input(shape = (386, 1024, 1), dtype = tf.float32)
x = layers.Dense(2)(inp)  # [None, 386, 1024, 2]
```

is not equivalent to following Torch code:

```
X = torch.randn(386, 1024, 1)
X = X.expand(386, 1024, 2)
X.shape [386, 1024, 2]
```

Since the `layers.Dense` in TF is equivalent to `nn.Linear` in Torch

Comment: Thank you so very much! I never would have guessed `nn.Linear(1, 2)`

Comment: @JohnStud Glad to help, Documentation is there for helping us so we don't have to guess : )